# post a status using different color in facebook wall from android application

Tags: android, facebook, android-edittext, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have to develop an one android application.

In my edittext message is displaying in green color.

now i want to post these green color message to my facebook wall from my android application.

```
String review = reviewEdit.getText().toString();

reviewEdit.setTextColor(color);
```

Here the color is green. These color from colorpicker functionality.

The message is posted successfully.But posting with black color.

But i want to post the message with the same green color. please refer the same image as same as i need.
[image: sameple output what i expected]

I want to post the message with selected color???

How can i do ????

I wrote the following code:

```
private void postToFacebook(String review) {    
    mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
    mProgress.show();
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", review);
    mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostListener());
}
```

I have posted the review defaultly black color.how can i post that review with green color.

please give me a solution ???

**EDIT:**

```
 String review = "<html><body>Sorry, <span style=\"background: red;\">Madonna</span> gave no results</body></html>";
```

This is my status...Now how can i post to facebook wall without html format .

please give me solution ???

Comment: If Facebook doesn't support posting colorful text on the wall, then I doubt you can achieve it though...

Comment: yes . But i want to change the default background color of status from my android application.How can i do ???? Any possible way to develop ???

Comment: I don't think you can change facebook status color from facebook API. But you may take a look into this link. http://www.askmefast.com/How_to_write_The_status_with_colour_font_in_facebook-qna524163.html#q2154413

Comment: _“please refer the same image as same as i need.”_ – I doubt that Mark would post status updates like that …